# How can I attach VS2012 to a IIS Application for debugging from the command line?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a web application hosted on my local machine. Is it possible to attach VS2012 to it from the command line given its process id?
How do I attach the current instance of VS2012 (with an open solution with breakpoints set) to a given w3P process id?

We need to do it for a developer instruction product.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Start → Run command → cmd
- Change directory to \Windows\System32
- Run the command: cscript iisapp.vbs

**Updated**

If you have process ID, To attach Visual Studio to that process from the command line.

On command prompt type `vsjitdebugger -p [process id]`

Comment: I can get the process id. I need the command to attach Visual Studio to that process from the command line.